# getClosestFeatureToCoordinate does not work for Points

Tags: openlayers-3

I made a function to get the closer feature to the one clicked. I use Openlayers 3.9.0 and the `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` method.

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();//simple click interaction
 map.addInteraction(select);//add it to the map

 select.on('select', function(e) {

   //get the extent of the first selected feature 
    var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();

   //in case of line or polygon get the center of that extent 
    var oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);

   //use it to get the name of the closest feature
   console.log((sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(oo)).get("mylayer_name")) ;
 });
```

But in a case like the following

[image]

if I click the "u" Polygon (bottom down) I get "u" instead of , say, "e"
if I click any point I get its name , instead of the closest feature's name. I click "testpoint9" and I get "testpoint9" instead of "u" or "e". I click "h" and I get "h" instead of "p" or "k".

So maybe has to do with points, so I changed the `select.on` event function to

```
select.on('select', function(e) {
    var closestType = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getType();
    var oo;
    if (closestType === 'Point'){
        oo = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    }
    else{
        var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
        oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);
    }

    console.log("---------------------------------------------------");
    console.log("Name: "+sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(oo).get('mylayer_name'));
})
```

and still nothing. So, how I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When You click inside the "u" polygon - the distance to it is 0.
When you click on something - that thing will always be the closest (to itself).
What you can do there, is removing the clicked element from the layer, run the algorithm (without clicked point) and put the point back on the layer.
If You are afraid that point could be invisible for too long (but it shouldn't), place it in another layer for the time of algorithm.

```
    select.on('select', function(e) {
        var clicked = e.selected[0];
        sourceVector.removeFeature(clicked);
        var closest = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(e.coordinate);
        sourceVector.addFeature(clicked);
        var closestType = closest.getType();
        if (closestType === 'Point'){
            oo = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        }
        else{
            var aa = e.selected[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
            oo = ol.extent.getCenter(aa);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for  your time and code, but, first of all, when you use `var closest = sourceVector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(oo);` what is the value of `oo` ?Isnt it empty?

Comment: More important, if I got you correctly, if I have to remove the feature, to get the coordinates, then I basicaly have to get the coordinates of the click on the map. I can do this with [getCoordinateFromPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getCoordinateFromPixel) without having to remove/add the clicked feature. But in this case the feature I just clicked will always be the closest to those map coordinates, so we back to the start. Either I dont get you at all, or, this is a serious OL issue.

Comment: event should have the coordinates itself. Then remove the feature, pass those coords to the function and put the feature back.